# Null Exception is posted everytime executing

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

This project has two parts.

1. .NETCore APIS
2. Postgre sql database.

I could connect with database but I could not update the table. Below I posted the Error.

**startup.cs file**

```
namespace Advantage.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private string _connectionString = null;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            _connectionString = Configuration["secretConnectionString"];

            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<ApiContext>(opt => opt.UseNpgsql(_connectionString));

            services.AddTransient <DataSeed>();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, DataSeed seed)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            seed.SeedData(2);
            app.UseMvc();

        }
    }
}
```

**dataseed.cs file**

```
namespace Advantage.API
{
    public class DataSeed
    {
        public readonly ApiContext _ctx;


        public DataSeed(ApiContext ctx)
        {

            _ctx = ctx;
        }

        public void SeedData(int nDatasets) 
        {
            if (!_ctx.Datasets.Any())
            {
                SeedDatasets(nDatasets);
                _ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
            if (!_ctx.Servers.Any())
            {
                SeedServers();
                _ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        private void SeedDatasets( int n )
        {
            List<Dataset> datasets = BuildDatasetList(n);

            foreach(var dataset in datasets)
            {
                _ctx.Datasets.Add(dataset);
            }

        }

        private void SeedServers()
        {
           List<Server> servers = BuildServerList();

           foreach(var server in servers) 
           {
               _ctx.Servers.Add(server);
           }
        }


        private List<Dataset> BuildDatasetList( int nDatasets)
        {
            var datasets = new List<Dataset>();

            for( var i = 1; i <= nDatasets; i++)
            {

                decimal temperature = Helpers.GetRandomTotal(); 
               // decimal humidity = Helpers.GetRandomTotal();
                var updated = Helpers.GetRandomUpdated();


                datasets.Add(new Dataset {
                    Id = i,
                    Temperature = temperature,
                    Humidity = Helpers.GetRandomTotal(),
                    Updated = updated 
                });
            } 

            return datasets;
        }



        private List<Server> BuildServerList()
        {
            return new List<Server>()
            {
                new Server{
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "Dev-web",
                    IsOnline = true

                },
                new Server{
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Dev-mail",
                    IsOnline = true

                },
                new Server{
                    Id = 3,
                    Name = "Dev-system",
                    IsOnline = false

                },
                new Server{
                    Id = 4,
                    Name = "QA-web",
                    IsOnline = true

                },
                new Server{
                    Id = 5,
                    Name = "QA-mail",
                    IsOnline = true

                },
                new Server{
                    Id = 6,
                    Name = "QA-system",
                    IsOnline = false

                }

            };
        } 


    }
}
```

I expect to update the database tables. Below i posted the Error.

> unhandled Exception: crit:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
>         Application startup exception System.Exception: Could not resolve a service of type 'Advantage.API.DataSeed' for the parameter
>   'seed' of method 'Configure' on type 'Advantage.API.Startup'. --->
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Comment: The `Configure` method is called *before* the `ConfigureServices` method. There's no service registration for `DataSeed` when `Configure` is called

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your reply. But It is called. Can you please notedown the service registration for DataSeed if you dont mind.

Comment: Called *where*? That's what the error complains about. When that method is called the service isn't registered

Comment: Still the Error is coming. Actually I am very fresh to .NET and C#. if you dont mind can you please tell me what i should do to resolve this problem -  Panagiotis Kanavos